# Google line charts doesn't show data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I have the following code that gives me a JSON output as follows:

```
[{ReadingDate: "2018-09-14 00:00:00", ReadingValues: "17796"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 23:45:00", ReadingValues: "17793"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 23:30:00", ReadingValues: "17791"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 23:15:00", ReadingValues: "17789"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 23:00:00", ReadingValues: "17786"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 22:45:00", ReadingValues: "17783"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 22:30:00", ReadingValues: "17781"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 22:15:00", ReadingValues: "17778"}
{ReadingDate: "2018-09-13 22:00:00", ReadingValues: "17776"}]
```

I have tested that the output from my action is being transmitted and received by the page and I am happy that it is. However, I cannot get it to draw the line chart with data in it.

My chart code is as follows:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

function drawLineChart() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');        
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');       

var options = {
    'legend': {
        'position': 'none'
    },
    'chartArea': {
        'width': '80%',
        'height': '80%'
    },
    title: 'Data'
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "CheckData")',
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (d) {  
        $.each(d, function (index, item) {  
            //data.addRows([[item.ReadingDate], [item.ReadingValues]]); 
            //data.addRows([item.ReadingDate], [item.ReadingValues]);                     
            data.addRows([item.ReadingDate, item.ReadingValues]);
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error loading chart data.")
    }
});

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

I want to plot the chart with the X-axis as the Date and the Y-axis as the value.

Comment: do you get any errors showing in console?

Comment: jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:97 Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.
    at gvjs_P.gvjs_.fZ (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:97)
    at gvjs_P.gvjs_.Op (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:98)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Index:132)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:354)
    at Object.success (Index:131)
    at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)
    at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9305)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (<anonymous>:1:781)

Comment: based on that, can you try `data.addRows(d);` instead of the for loop?  (you do not need to add the rows one by one from your data array `d` )

Comment: I have tried that and still get the same error. I have tested the JSON output in a test ajax call and it looks fine.

Comment: `addrows` expect an array of arrays - so it would be `data.addRows([[item.ReadingDate, item.ReadingValues]]);` (although it would be better to either generate the correct data in the controller, or build the array of arrays in the $.each()` function so that you use `addRows()` once

Comment: Do not edit your question to show the correct code as per comments and answers (its no longer a question). I have rolled back you changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First put below line before $ajax call

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div'));
```

then replace the success code with

```
$.each(d, function (index, item) {  
   data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), parseInt(item.ReadingValues)]);
});
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Your code had three issues,

1. You have to pass a multidimensional array if you use data.addRows otherwise use data.addRow
2. You define the data type as date and number but pass date as string and figure as a string. Which handle by conversion.
3. You called the chart.draw just after initiating the ajax call. As ajax calls are asynchronous, google chart never receives any data object. TO fix that put the draw chart code in success function.

Comment: The line of code that worked was '  data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), parseInt(item.ReadingValues)]);'.  As you mentioned, by not casting the date, it was not seeing it as a proper value.

Comment: The only problem I have, is that the number maybe a decimal number sometimes so I have changed it to ' data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), Number(item.ReadingValues)]);'

Comment: Nope, you should get a blank graph because you are not waiting for the ajax call to complete. Maybe you are on local but when some delay occurs it will cause the problem of a blank graph.

Comment: Yes, i am on local. I have changed it as you said, just in case when it goes live. Thanks for your help.